# is it possible to get products filtered by out of stock by date?

Tags: stock, inventory, stock-status, cataloginventory

Is it possible to get all products filtered by out of stock by date? This will give the function to see when the products was last in stock, and give us the information to delete product if necessary.

Comment: The question is not clear. From where do you want to delete the products? Orders with products no longer in stock? If that is the case you can simply disable backorders from Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog Tab -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options -> Backorders and stop accepting orders with out of stock products.

Comment: Sorry for not being cleared enough. 

I have in total 450 products in my shop, and around 200 are out of stock. Other 250 are in stock. I have chose the option to show only products which are in stock, so my shop displays only in stock products, which is what i wanted. Now my question is related to out of stock products. I would like to delete them from the catalog permanently, but need to know the information when the product was last time in stock. Logically I would delete older out of stock product/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento ***does not save  the stock change date & time in it  Inventory module.***

So, you ***cannot it get  older out of stock products from system.***

You can only *`get out of stock product list`*.

Comment: is anyway to show out of stock products only for specific category?